# What connection protocol does JADE use for agent to agent connection over network?

Tags: networking, agents-jade

Does anyone know that what kind of connection protocol does Java Agent Development (JADE) uses to provide over-network connection between agents for sending ACLMessages? (for example is it SSH connection or waht)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JADE has implemented an own small web server that uses HTTP, HTTPS or both for the MTP (**M**essage **T**ransport **P**rotocol).

To specify the type, you can configure the MTP / MessagingService of JADE by start arguments from command line or via `Profile` from your own code. Details for command line arguments can be found in the ['JADE ADMINISTRATOR’S GUIDE'](https://jade.tilab.com/doc/administratorsguide.pdf). Details for defining a Profile can be found in the source code and the JADE book.